# Cypress - fake internet failure

Tags: testing, cypress

I'm writing my code with Cypress and want to test a case where internet failure or server doesn't return any response. I'm looking around Cypress docs but found nothing that can help. The closest thing that I can find is

```
cy.route({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'my_url',
    response: {},
})
.as('validate');
```

The problem is that I can't replace the response with undefined, cause cypress doesn't allow it. And if I remove it, Cypress will stop mocking my API. Any helps?

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'redirect'.

https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route.html#Simulate-a-server-redirect

```
describe('response will be empty', function() 
{
it('Open web page',()=> {
    let url = 'https://www.google.com/maps';
    cy.server();
    cy.route(
    {
        method: 'GET',
        url: '**/maps/**',
        //you can replace the status code you like 
        status: 503,
        response: {
            redirect: ''
        }
    }
    );
    cy.visit(url);
})
})
```

The response will be empty string. See screenshot below,
[image]

If you use

```
response: {}
```

It will return emtpy response body.

Comment: The response here is still empty string, not undefined or null. Should the empty response mean this?

Comment: I think in this case it will return the repsonse with empty string in the body. I modified my answer for empty body too. If you want to have no response coming back probably route command is not the correct way.